# ASP.NET Core encryption and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am creating a default user for my system. However I am creating through SQL Server database.

I use ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework to handle logins, by default Entity Framework creates a table called `AspNetUsers`; this table has a column called `PasswordHash`, I believe the encryption used is of the Hash type.

I am entering the password on this user by the database as follows:

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'Administrador');  

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis)

UPDATE AspNetUsers 
SET PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA1', @HashThis), 
    SecurityStamp = '0b12450e-016d-4cd6-af7b-fa6d2198586f', 
    ConcurrencyStamp = 'a63a5236-4020-4f69-93b1-9f077ba014cd', 
    UserName = 'administrador@administrador.com.br'
```

But the password column is getting strange characters in Japanese, it follows the image:

[image]

The biggest issue and when I log in ASP.NET Core, only the password invalidates.

How can I do to bypass this?

Observation: when I create the user through ASP.NET Core, it works normally.

Comment: Thats not how you calculate the hash. You should use seeding on your first application start to create an user when the app starts, using the UserManager class. Only this will generate you a  correct cash (its more complicated than calculating the a specific hash, it also involves a security stamp, specific algorithms and encoding all of this in a non-binary format so it can be stored). You'd be better off creating this once on the development system and export the row as sql statement and run that on production

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for replying, it's really quite complicated. I had not thought of that, I'm going to do exactly what you said. I will do a check to see if a user already exists, and there is no one through the application before the user makes the login attempt. I believe that this will work. I'll try and give you a comeback. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example how you can seed you user:

In you SecurityDbContext you can create following methods (I added SeedRoles in case you need them):

```
 public static async Task Seed(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        await SeedRoles(serviceProvider);
        await SeedUsers(serviceProvider);
    }
```

Seed Roles:

```
public static async Task SeedRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();

        string[] roles = ...;

        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            ApplicationRole appRole = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role);
            if (appRole == null)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(role));
            }
        }
    }
```

Seed User:

```
public static async Task SeedUser(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,  string email, string password, string roleName = "")
    {
        string userName = roleName;

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        if (user == null)
        {
            // Create user account if it doesn't exist
            user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = userName,
                Email = email
            };

            IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

            // Assign role to the user
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            }

        }

        if (user != null && roleName.Length > 0)
        {
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName);
        }
    }
```

From SeedUsers method, just call SeedUser as many times as you need.

And then just simply call Seed method from Startup.cs Configure method:

```
SecurityDbContextSeed.Seed(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
```